# Products not appearing in shopping cart when using AJAX and session storage in PHP eCommerce project

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Products not appearing in shopping cart when using AJAX and session storage in PHP eCommerce project.

I have been working on an eCommerce project in PHP where I'm implementing a shopping cart functionality. I have a products.php page that displays a list of products, and each product has an "Add to Cart" button. When the user clicks the button, I use AJAX to send the selected product to the server and store it in the session storage.

The issue I'm facing is that when I navigate to the cart.php page to view the cart contents, the products added from the products.php page are not appearing in the cart. Instead, I see the message "No items in the cart" even though I can verify in the session storage that the cart items are being stored correctly.

I have checked my JavaScript code for adding products to the cart and it seems to be working fine. I also ensured that the session is started and the database connection is established in cart.php. However, I'm unable to figure out why the cart items are not being retrieved and displayed in the cart.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the products added to the cart are correctly displayed in the cart.php page.

What I tried:
I have checked the JavaScript code responsible for adding products to the cart and it appears to be functioning correctly. I also ensured that the session is started and the database connection is established in cart.php.

What I expected:
I expected the products added to the cart from the products.php page to be displayed in the cart.php page. The cart items should be retrieved from the session and rendered in the cart table.

What actually resulted:
However, when I navigate to the cart.php page, it shows the message "No items in the cart" instead of displaying the products that were added from the products.php page. I have confirmed that the cart items are being stored correctly in the session storage, but they are not being retrieved and displayed in the cart.

I'm seeking assistance to understand why the products are not appearing in the cart and how to resolve this issue.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

## products.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, name, price, description, image FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div id="success-message"></div>
<main>
    <section class="product-listing">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $imageSrc = 'images/' . $row['image'];
        ?>
        <div class="product-wrapper">
            <div class="product">
                <img src="<?php echo $imageSrc; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                <h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
                <p>$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></p>
                <button class="add-to-cart" data-product-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </section>
</main>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

<?php
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

## add_to_cart.js:

```
// Add event listeners to the "Add to Cart" buttons
var addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');
addToCartButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCart);
});

// Function to handle adding a product to the cart
function addToCart(event) {
  var productId = event.target.getAttribute('data-product-id');
  console.log('Adding product to cart:', productId);

  // Example: Store the product in the session storage
  var cartItems = sessionStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) : [];
  cartItems.push({ id: productId, quantity: 1 });
  sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

  // Example: Update the cart badge
  updateCartBadge();

  // Example: Provide feedback to the user
  alert('Product added to the cart!');

  // Send the cart items to the PHP file
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'cart.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Handle the response from cart.php if needed
    }
  };
  
  // Prepare the cart items data to be sent
  var cartData = 'cartItems=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(cartItems));

  // Send the cart items data
  xhr.send(cartData);
  
  // Redirect to the cart page
  window.location.href = 'cart.php';
}

// Function to update the cart badge
function updateCartBadge() {
    var cartItems = sessionStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) : [];
    console.log('Cart items:', cartItems);
    var cartBadge = document.getElementById('cart-badge');
    cartBadge.textContent = cartItems.length;
  }
```

## cart.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';

// Receive the cart items from the AJAX request
$cartItems = isset($_POST['cartItems']) ? json_decode($_POST['cartItems'], true) : [];

// Store the cart items in the session
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cartItems;

// Print the cart items
$string = "This Cart Items: ";
var_dump($string, $cartItems);

?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<section class="cart">
    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $totalAmount = 0;
        if (!empty($cartItems)) {
            foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
                $productId = $cartItem['id'];
                $quantity = $cartItem['quantity'];
                // Retrieve the product details from the database using $productId
                $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $productId";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                    // Calculate the subtotal for the current product
                    $subtotal = $product['price'] * $quantity;

                    // Add the subtotal to the total amount
                    $totalAmount += $subtotal;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" min="1" data-product-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>">
                <button class="update-quantity">Update</button>
            </td>
            <td>$<?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
            <td>$<?php echo $subtotal; ?></td>
            <td><a href="remove_from_cart.php?id=<?php echo $productId; ?>">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }} } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">No items in the cart</td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>Total: $<?php echo $totalAmount; ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>


<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

## cart.js:

```
function updateQuantity(event) {
    var productId = event.target.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('data-product-id');
    var quantity = event.target.previousElementSibling.value;

    // Get the updated cart items from the sessionStorage
    var cartItems = sessionStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) : [];
    // Find the item in the cart with the matching productId
    var index = cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === productId);
    if (index !== -1) {
        // Update the quantity for the item
        cartItems[index].quantity = quantity;
        // Store the updated cart items in the sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    }

    // Example: Update the cart badge and total amount
    updateCartBadge();
    updateTotalAmount();

    // Example: Provide feedback to the user
    alert('Quantity updated!');
}
```

Comment: _"The issue I'm facing is that when I navigate to the cart.php page to view the cart contents"_ - you "navigating" there, means clicking a link pointing to `cart.php` in the frontend, yes? So your browser will make a GET request then. And what do you do, when `$_POST['cartItems']` is not set (which it will of course not be, on a GET request)? You make `$cartItems` an empty array, and then you are storing that into your session, `$_SESSION['cart'] = $cartItems;` So of course your cart is empty now.